# Hbase Bulkload append Data instead overwrite them

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

acutally I'am loading Data into Hbase with the help of Mapreduce and Bulkload, which I implemented in Java. 
So basically I created a Mapper and use `HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad` (full code at the end of the question) for reduce and i use a mapper which simply reads in some bytes from file and create a put. Writing this out an using `LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad` to write the Data into Hbase. This all works pretty well. But for sure when do this it overwrites old values in Hbase. So I'am searching for a way to append the Data, like the append function from api works. 
Thanks for reading and hopefully some of you have an Idea that can help me :)

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int result=0;
    String outputPath = args[1];
    Configuration configuration = getConf();
    configuration.set("data.seperator", DATA_SEPERATOR);
    configuration.set("hbase.table.name",TABLE_NAME);
    configuration.set("COLUMN_FAMILY_1",COLUMN_FAMILY_1);
    configuration.set("COLUMN_FAMILY_2",COLUMN_FAMILY_2);

    Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration);
    job.setJarByClass(HBaseBulkLoadDriver.class);
    job.setJobName("Bulk Loading HBase Table::"+TABLE_NAME);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setMapperClass(HBaseBulkLoadMapper.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, args[0]);
    FileSystem.getLocal(getConf()).delete(new Path(outputPath), true);
    HFileOutputFormat2.setOutputPath(job,new Path((outputPath)));
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);
    Connection c = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration);
    Table t = c.getTable(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));
    RegionLocator rl = c.getRegionLocator(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));
    HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job,t,rl);
    System.out.println("start");
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    if (job.isSuccessful()) {
        HBaseBulkLoad.doBulkLoad(outputPath, TABLE_NAME);
    } else {

        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}



public static void doBulkLoad(String pathToHFile, String tableName) {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.set("mapreduce.child.java.opts", "-Xmx1g");
        HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(configuration);
        LoadIncrementalHFiles loadFfiles = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(configuration);


        //HTable hTable = new HTable(configuration, tableName);
        //loadFfiles.doBulkLoad(new Path(pathToHFile), hTable);

        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration);
        Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
        Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
        RegionLocator regionLocator = connection.getRegionLocator(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
        //path, admin, table, region locator
        loadFfiles.doBulkLoad(new Path(pathToHFile),admin,table,regionLocator);


        System.out.println("Bulk Load Completed..");
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As requested in the comments, i add here the output of the table description, cause the table was created by the python happybase api and i'am not sure what optionflags the api is setting by default...

`{NAME => '0', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_B
LOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'false', BLO
CKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}

{NAME => '1', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_B
LOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'false', BLO
CKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}`

Comment: HBase bulk load appends data by default and doesn't erase old date except  that case if you configured your table and column family for storing only one version of a row. Could you add to the post how did you create your table?

Comment: Hey, i created the Table with the Happybase api, so added the table description...  When i tried my source Code an put in two different values for the same combination of rowkey, family and column descriptor and then retrieved the column from this row i only getting the last value. But i would like to have something like "Value1Value2" if the first put puts in the String Value1 and the second one puts in Value2

Comment: How did you check that there is only one version of row after two keys? And what happens if you try to insert two different keys during two separate bulk loads?

Comment: Hey i checked back and found out, that there are instead different versions of the key, when i do 2 bulkloads... But if if have value0 and value1 in the same file and then try a bulkload of this file i only get a single Version where  the first value in File is overwritten... As i said in the Question i wish the behavior that hbase simply concats the bytes of the values ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad() http://atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.hbase/hbase-server/1.2.4/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/HFileOutputFormat2.html#line.408
PutSortReducer is used as a reducer.

In PutSortReducer.reduce() http://atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.hbase/hbase-server/1.2.4/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/PutSortReducer.html
KeyValues are stored in a TreeSet, with a comparator comparing keys only. That is why only one value survives.

To keep the 2 values, you may create your own reducer, based on PutSortReducer, where you can keep the 2 values. And set it:

HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job,t,rl);
job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

Comment: Yeah creating a custom reducer might work, so you don't overwrite files with same key for this bulkload, but it does not solve the other problem, that i would like to add the data from file to the exsisting version insted of creating a new one..

Comment: Overwriting the existing version is a general HBase behavior, not bulkload specific. To solve it, in the custom reducer, you may read the data from HBase, and append the new value.

Comment: Yeah I know that, that is an general behavior, but i would like to find a way like the append function which reads the data one the region server and concat the bytes from input and the old ones...